# Implementing a popup page for a web blog on clicking a link

Tags: html

How do I go about implementing something like this ? (the clicking on the site feature)

http://ideas-to-implement.blogspot.in/

i already have a template with me and i wud like to overlay it with this . I know how I wud popup an image in a webpage (clicking on the image enlarges it , I mean) . I tried using the same logic with the webpage , but it did not work .

Also , it is just something my manager has asked me to do (And I only have firsthand knowledge of JSP , php and other web technologies ).So , please help me out . Not one of those homework problems .

Answer (score 0):

You need to open a page in a popup?

Try http://fancybox.net/
It's like a modal box, but you can put pages in it. 
If you use .jsp and struts2 it's very easy.

Is this what you are looking for?